# My console is showing an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

It's showing on line four

```
var questions =[{
    question: "Who was the King after God's heart?",
    Choices: ["Adam", "Solomon", "Daniel", "David"]
    correctAnswer: 3
}]
```

Comment: Could you post the full error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 2):

you just forgot a comma

```
var questions =[{ question: "Who was the King after God's heart?", Choices: ["Adam", "Solomon", "Daniel", "David"], correctAnswer: 3 }]
```

```js
var questions =[
   { 
      question: "Who was the King after God's heart?", 
      Choices: ["Adam", "Solomon", "Daniel", "David"], // this is the comma you forgot 
      correctAnswer: 3 
   }
 ]
 
 console.log(questions)
```